# Writing variables to csv rows with Python

Tags: python

My python script counts how many times a word list appears in a text. Script works but when I try to write results in a CSV file separated by semicolons but it doesn't work.

My code:

```
import csv
wordslist = ["Bob", "car"]
text = "Bob loves his Mustang car, but Bob wants a Ferrari car because Ferrari is a fastest car."
for word in wordslist :
    resultCar = str(word) + "; " + str(text.count(word))
    print resultCar
    carCountsCsv = open("carcounts.csv", "wb")
    with carCountsCsv:
        writer = csv.writer(carCountsCsv)
        writer.writerow(resultCar)
```

And my CSV file results is:

```
c,a,r,;, ,3
```

I don't understand why my result appear in the same row, I want to have this result like in the console:

```
Bob;2
car;3
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I get the result, that you want. with python2.7. Are you sure?

Comment: I just update my question, `c,a,r,;, ,3` is my CSV file result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, open the file once before the loop, otherwise you will overwrite the previous line and will end up with a file that only contains the last row.

```
with open("carcounts.csv", "w") as carCountsCsv:
```

Then, since you want `;` as the separator in your CSV file, you don't need to use `csv_writer`. You've already created a string with the right separator. Just write the lines to a normal file.

```
with open("carcounts.csv", "w") as carCountsCsv:
    for word in wordslist :
        resultCar = str(word) + "; " + str(text.count(word)) + "\n"
        print(resultCar)
        carCountsCsv.write(resultCar)
```

If you do want to use the CSV library, you will want to pass it the delimiter that you want when you create the writer. Then you pass it a list with the elements of each row and it will add the delimiter for you.

```
with open("carcounts.csv", "w", newline='') as carCountsCsv:
    writer = csv.writer(carCountsCsv, delimiter=';')
    for word in wordslist:
        resultCar = [str(word), str(text.count(word))]
        print(resultCar)
        writer.writerow(resultCar)
```

Note that when you open the file, specify `newline=''`. The `csv.writer` will add the newline for you. If you forget this, you will get double newlines in your CSV file.

Comment: I get a `AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'writeline'` error.

Comment: @AmirA.Shabani - it was a typo. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Since your output is CSV already, consider raw pipe. Say our file is named `bob_car.py`.

```
wordslist = ["Bob", "car"]
text = "Bob loves his Mustang car, but Bob wants a Ferrari car because Ferrari is a fastest car."
for word in wordslist:
    print "%s; %i" % (word, text.count(word))
```

Then simply do:

```
python bob_car.py > carcounts.csv
```

Comment: Thank you too, I think it's better syntax.